# Send request for firebase notification from the app

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase service for push notification in my Android app. The service is working great and I am able to send notifications from the firebase console admin to all users and to single user.

My question is: I want to send automatic notification (not using admin) after user publish post on the app.

1. User publish post
2. Send request to firebase API with user ID
3. Firebase generate task notification (30 min) and send to the user

Where to start? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use okHttp3 library to send request to firebase to send notification to particular user.

```
 RequestBody requestBody = null;
            try {
                requestBody = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JSON, getValidJsonBody().toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .addHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .addHeader(AUTHORIZATION, AUTH_KEY)
                    .url(FCM_URL)
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .build();

            Call call = new OkHttpClient().newCall(request);
            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onGetAllUsersFailure: " + e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    if (response.isSuccessful())
                        Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().string());
                }
            });
        }

        private JSONObject getValidJsonBody() throws JSONException {
            JSONObject jsonObjectBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonObjectBody.put(KEY_TO, mReceiverFirebaseToken);

            JSONObject jsonObjectData = new JSONObject();
            jsonObjectData.put(KEY_TITLE, mTitle);
            jsonObjectData.put(KEY_TEXT, mMessage);
            jsonObjectData.put(KEY_USERNAME, mUsername);
            jsonObjectData.put(KEY_UID, mUid);
            jsonObjectData.put(KEY_FCM_TOKEN, mFirebaseToken);
            jsonObjectBody.put(KEY_DATA, jsonObjectData);

            return jsonObjectBody;
        }
```